# Run a batch file in Python which contains java command

Tags: java, python, batch-file

It is quite frustrating when you can't execute a .bat file in python while it is executing manually.

I am attaching my code here:

```
directory = 'E:/'
with open(os.path.join(directory, 'output_file.bat'), 'w') as OPATH:
    OPATH.writelines(['"""',"\n"'E:',"\n",
                      'javacCreatingUser.java',"\n",'javaCreatingUser',"\n",'"""'])

os.system("E:/output_file.bat")
```

The above is my python code which is creating a bat file with 2 java command

1. `javac CreatingUser.java`
2. `java CreatingUser`

I can run the .bat file manually and it is working fine but my python script is giving me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/iam/identity/exception/ValidationFailedException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.iam.identity.exception.ValidationFailedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" '"""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
```

The question is that if some classes are missing in my file then it should not execute manually as well, but manual execution is fine.

Comment: Do you need a space after javac in your writelines?

Comment: Paths on windows systems have backslashes in them, not forward slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
javac CreatingUser.java
java CreatingUser
```

This is the source of your problem: You're only compiling one class file and then calling that class without a classpath.

Java has a search path for classes comparable to Pythons `PYTHONPATH` called [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

You can give this a try:

```
javac CreatingUser.java
java -classpath YOUR_CLASSPATH CreatingUser
```

`YOUR_CLASSPATH` can be a colon (Linux) or semicolon (Windows) separated list of JAR files and directories containing class files. Let your classpath point to the JARs you're needing and you're fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however i have already updated the classpath in my environment variable

Comment: and also why i am able to execute the bat file manually without passing the classpath but not through the python script

Comment: You want `E:\output_file.bat`.

Comment: Use absolute paths in your classpath. Relative paths will always depend on your current working directory.